# If one was groomed as a child, can they be found innocent as an adult?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, california, juvenile-law, adult

Dave the Dad is the father of Bob the boy. Dave groomed Bob to murder minorities from a young age.

If Bob went on to murder some minority at age 12, Bob wouldn't just be given consequences like some random adult who'd committed such a heinous act. More likely, Bob would be given counseling, while Dave would be held responsible.

But what if Bob was groomed by his dad Dave all the way to age 18, and went on the same murder spree? Or up until the age 21? Or whatever reasonable age have you.

My main question is: can Bob be exonerated in any way because he was groomed by an adult (even into his own adulthood)?

To clarify: please do not use "threatening" in your answer. Dave grooming Bob is different than someone "threatening" Bob to do something. Also, "murdering minorities" is a random example that may not be perfect. Feel free to substitute in something more appropriate so as not to distract from the heart of the question (e.g. committing shop-lifting, murdering women, selling meth, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

No: mitigating factors short of duress or other defences like necessity or self defence do not excuse or justify a crime that is otherwise proven.

Mitigating factors must be taken into account during sentencing. History of abuse is a personal circumstance that can be taken into account: e.g. *R. v. Farrell*, 2013 BCSC 1537 at [para 9](https://canlii.ca/t/g06d5#par9). Same for "parental introduction into the criminal lifestyle": *R. v. L.T.N.*, 2021 SKCA 73, at [para 61](https://canlii.ca/t/jfs52#par61).

Answer (score 0):

In ordinary English, "grooming" is when a social superior (in some sense) does normal, legal things to encourage a person to follow a certain path, e.g. "groomed him to take over the company". It has recently gained a secondary meaning of befriending a minor for illicit sexual purposes, but that sense is clearly not applicable here. Instead, Dave has encouraged Bob to commit illegal acts.

Although serious childhood abuse could constitute a mitigating factor in the case of Bob committing a crime as an adult, there are typically statutory statements as to what factors are relevant. [Here](https://apps.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=9.94A.535) is the Washington state list, which is suggestive, not exhaustive:

> (a) To a significant degree, the victim was an initiator, willing
> participant, aggressor, or provoker of the incident. (b) Before
> detection, the defendant compensated, or made a good faith effort to
> compensate, the victim of the criminal conduct for any damage or
> injury sustained. (c) The defendant committed the crime under duress,
> coercion, threat, or compulsion insufficient to constitute a complete
> defense but which significantly affected his or her conduct. (d) The
> defendant, with no apparent predisposition to do so, was induced by
> others to participate in the crime. (e) The defendant's capacity to
> appreciate the wrongfulness of his or her conduct, or to conform his
> or her conduct to the requirements of the law, was significantly
> impaired. Voluntary use of drugs or alcohol is excluded. (f) The
> offense was principally accomplished by another person and the
> defendant manifested extreme caution or sincere concern for the safety
> or well-being of the victim. (g) The operation of the multiple offense
> policy of RCW 9.94A.589 results in a presumptive sentence that is
> clearly excessive in light of the purpose of this chapter, as
> expressed in RCW 9.94A.010. (h) The defendant or the defendant's
> children suffered a continuing pattern of physical or sexual abuse by
> the victim of the offense and the offense is a response to that abuse.
> (i) The defendant was making a good faith effort to obtain or provide
> medical assistance for someone who is experiencing a drug-related
> overdose. (j) The current offense involved domestic violence, as
> defined in RCW 10.99.020, and the defendant suffered a continuing
> pattern of coercion, control, or abuse by the victim of the offense
> and the offense is a response to that coercion, control, or abuse. (k)
> The defendant was convicted of vehicular homicide, by the operation of
> a vehicle in a reckless manner and has committed no other previous
> serious traffic offenses as defined in RCW 9.94A.030, and the sentence
> is clearly excessive in light of the purpose of this chapter, as
> expressed in RCW 9.94A.010.

The only clause that comes close, and it is not close enough, is

> (h) The defendant or the defendant's children suffered a continuing
> pattern of physical or sexual abuse by the victim of the offense and
> the offense is a response to that abuse

Being badly brought up is not a mitigating factor for sentencing, and certainly not a defense.

Answer (score 0):

### No in [germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

Instead of just holding Bob accountable for murder, both Bob and Dave are very likely accountable for it: Bob for doing it for low reasons (in this case: hatred), and Dave for "Anstiftung" under [§26 StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__26.html). Both are to be punished with prison for life.